# Flutter riverpod provider not displaying correct data

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a Riverpod provider created as such:

```
@riverpod
class SelectedEntities extends _$SelectedEntities {
  @override
  Set<FileOfInterest> build(FileType type) {
    return {};
  }

  void add(FileOfInterest entity) {
    if (!state.contains(entity)) {
      state = { ...state, entity};
    }
  }
}
```

I can add to the provider as expected using ref.read, if I do so, the ProviderObserver shows the output as I would expect:

```
flutter: selectedEntitiesProvider(PreviewGrid): {picture.jpg}
```

I have a PreviewGrid which uses ref.watch to look for the data from the provider. If the PreviewGrid has never been opened (I need to click on a button to show it) and I then open it, the provider is showing as empty:

```
flutter: PreviewGrid.build(): {}
```

(from a debugPrint in the build function of the PreviewGrid). If the PreviewGrid is already open though, when I select the file, everything shows up as expected:

```
flutter: selectedEntitiesProvider(PreviewGrid): {picture.jpg} // ProviderObserver output
flutter: PreviewGrid.build(): {picture.jpg}
```

What am I missing, please?

Given Riverpod providers operate outside the Widget tree, not sure why I am getting disoarate results based on Visibility...

Comment: Your generated provider is defaulting to autodispose.  If you're not holding a ref.watch on the provider somewhere, it will reset.

Answer (score 0):

As @Randal Schwartz correctly pointed out:

> Your generated provider is defaulting to autodispose. If you're not holding a ref.watch on the provider somewhere, it will reset.

There are two solutions to this dilemma:

1. Use the `@Riverpod` annotation and in it the `keepAlive` parameter, then your code will look like this:

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class SelectedEntities extends _$SelectedEntities {...}
```

This will allow your state to be created the first time `selectedEntitiesProvider` is accessed and then held even if the provider is no longer `watch`ing. Some kind of state caching!

2. In the widget above your `PreviewGrid` on the widget tree, add a listener to the `build` or `initState` method. And your provider will live on as long as it's bugged by this widget:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.listen(selectedEntitiesProvider, (_, __) {});
    return ...;
  }
```

Comment: That sorted it. Thanks. And to Randall. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DavidHobley Good coding to you! Mark the question as correct so it will help others too :)